# how can i define the result of sum function as float?

Tags: sql

```
SELECT @ResultVar = SUM(CASE WHEN Budget_Qr IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE Budget_Qr END)
```

I want the result to return a Float value.

Comment: What about the function `CAST` ?

Comment: What data type is `Budget_Qr`? What data type is `@ResultVar`?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? The above code isn't valid ANSI SQL.

Comment: I will try the CAST

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not knowing the data type of `Budget_Qr` makes it a bit tricky to answer. You likely can use the `CAST` function. Also, do the very simple sanity check to make sure that the variable `@ResultVar` has been declared with an appropriate data type. Also, in your snippet I do not know if you omitted parts of the SQL statement to focus on the issue or not.

If the column `Budget_Qr` is not a `FLOAT` you can do something like:

```sql
DECLARE @ResultVar AS FLOAT;

SELECT @ResultVar = 
    SUM(
        CASE WHEN Budget_Qr IS NULL THEN CAST(0 AS FLOAT) 
        ELSE CAST(Budget_Qr AS FLOAT) 
        END
    ) 
FROM SomeTable;
```

Many RDBMS systems have built-in functions to deal with `NULL` values and setting a default. If you happen to be running SQL Server (and a few others), the following would do the same thing as the above statement:

```sql
DECLARE @ResultVar AS FLOAT;

SELECT @ResultVar = SUM(CAST(COALESCE(Budget_Qr, 0) AS FLOAT)) 
FROM SomeTable;
```

You can always check the documentation for your specific RDBMS to see what functions are available.